# how to type the return value of a method in an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a simple TypeScript module, it is a function that you give it an object, and it invokes all the functions and sets the values on the same properties.

and if any property in the object isn't a function, it doesn't do anything with it and just ignores it.

The following is the full functional source code, it works and that's all of it, the only thing left for me is to convert it from vanilla JavaScript into Typescript.

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

export default function flexifyParams(params) {
  const composedObject = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    composedObject[key] = _.isFunction(value) ? value() : value
  }
  return composedObject
}
```

Here's a good example of how this function will work:

```js
const test = {
  x: () => 'hi',
  y: () => 123,
  z: () => ["a", "b", "c"],
  a: 'my string',
}
const P = flexifyParams(test)

// P is equal to:
//  {
//     x: 'hi',
//     y: 123,
//     z: ["a", "b", "c"],
//     a: 'my string',
//   }
```

Now, here's what I have tried so far, I tried to re-write this function using typescript and here's the code:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

export default function flexifyParams<PARAMS extends object>(params: PARAMS): PARAMS {
  const composedObject: { [index: string]: string | Symbol | number } = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    composedObject[key] = _.isFunction(value) ? value() : value
  }
  return composedObject as PARAMS
}
```

it still works, however, the function return value type isn't totally correct.

It's correct that the return value will hold the same object keys given in the parameter, but their values aren't the same, their values are the return value of the given methods.

How can I type the return value of this function correctly using TypeScript?

Comment: Unless this question actually depends on lodash it would be best if the example doesn't require it; but since I think we're just asking about typings and not implementation I guess it doesn't matter.  Also, you haven't said this, but I assume it's important that `flexifyParams()` rejects objects containing functions that require arguments, like `{oops: (x: string) => x.toUpperCase()}`, which would throw an error at runtime.   Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wzk84w) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not filtering the return type and are returning `PARAMS`, for your requirement this declaration is too meaningless

> I will remove lodash from my answer because i don't like it

```
export default function flexifyParams<PARAMS extends object>(params: PARAMS): {
  [K in keyof PARAMS]: PARAMS[K]extends (...t: any) => infer R ? R :  PARAMS[K]
} {
  const composedObject: any = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    composedObject[key] = typeof (value) === 'function' ? value() : value
  }
  return composedObject
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAEATUAzAhgVwDZLVgHYDG8AltIYmjhGWgJ4AKGsGAtgM4A8TAggCU+AWQDKiCPFCFknRNABGAK1CkAfAApIrDpwBcifkLEBKAwG9giRAG0A0ojJUA1qAbQ0hwSNEBdA0Y+9r6S0rKIGgB00fAGGIQMJogAvGqOhGigsIgCiAD8OYgGXsaiwcAAvoiW1sSUnEh17DCcoMgA8sqqsYjxDCnVFVbUcBF1hA22rgwANIgAbhg4WKC+8p6dKqSR0vCwZKCcWjpcJkk11ohNLW2b3TbTa8mI8AyQoB4Ri8ugScn-iAA5AQSORKID8gslisNEkDN8VsMhtZYKB4FhYFRrtBWh0uqRKiBxpMpJNnhdwAZYSk0oCABZkQEzYYMKl-NIARgATABmZnWABebJptgARBhRXNRQpJYhRcRRb5+b0DID2P0GvtCABzJmE4lIJgDGh0RgsNhcDSk+AmIA)

Comment: Wow, you're a typescript wizard! what does the `K in keyof PARAMS` part in the index signature mean?

Comment: it means `K` will have to be a key of `PARAMS`